# Pass certificate / key to Identity Server 4 when launching from Docker container for Linux

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate, identityserver4, blazor-client-side

I'm trying to get a Blazor Web Assembly app up and running with authentication for deployment on Digital Ocean, but I can't for the life of me seem to load a .pfx cert to pass it to Identity Server when trying to run within docker container.

I load and pass the certificate in `Startup` like so:

```
string password = "password";
string certificate = "IdSrv.pfx";
            var cert = new X509Certificate2(
                certificate,
                password,
                X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet |
                X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet |
                X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<JccUser, JccContext>()
                .AddSigningCredential(cert);
```

But when trying to run container and mount the path to the certificate I just can't seem to locate the file.

```
`docker run --rm -it -p 8000:80 -p 8001:443 
-e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+" -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=8001 
-e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="password" 
-e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/cert.pfx 
// for SSL
-v C:\Users\user\.aspnet\https:/https/ 
// for Identity Server (I tried using the same for both originally)
-v C:\Users\user\.cert\IdSrv.pfx:/IdSrv.pfx
docker-name`
```

I get `Unhandled exception. Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error
:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file`

In AppSettings.json I just have the boiler plate

```
"IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "Jcc.Client": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      } } },
```

But as I understand it, I don't need to configure the key in there if I am doing at `AddSigningCredentuial()`.
I must be missing something obvious or have got the wrong end of the stick somewhere?

Comment: could be because of permissions too open, try to build the container with the certificate and key instead of mounting and change the permission to 400 just to see if that's the issue (also check that the file is actually there).

Comment: could be that the files are not there, try mounting using the / syntax, with /c/Users...

Comment: Do you mean by using CP/ADD in the Dockerfile? There is definitely a file there, and the mounting seems to work for the first certificate, the SSL called 'cert' above to allow HTTPS on kestrel (although that is probably redundant using reverse proxy).

Comment: yeah, add the files with ADD, but change the permissions, that's the important part

Comment: Added the file, CHMOD to 644, but unless I'm referencing it incorrectly from AppSettings I still can't find it.  If I ADD ["./IdSrv.pfx", "App/Server/"]   
RUN chmod 644 App/Server/IdSrv.pfx    
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "App.Server.dll"], Would you think that the cert could be referenced from "./IdSrv.pfx ?

Comment: well my feeling is that the error message is misleading, but I could be wrong. Experiment with a few more combinations, like 400 and 600 (I had issues with this kind of stuff in other situations). I am not familiar with BWA and I don't know exactly what container your running or how it's built. The problem might be in the app itself also, but I really can't help you beyond this point, sorry. Also I would suggest bashing into the container and manually starting the app instead of relying on the entrypoint so that you can debug better, maybe you can pass some flag to see more debug information

Comment: Praise be, I finally located it! Thanks for the tip re removing the ENTRY POINT, that enable me to poke around in the container file system and find out where the certificate got mounted to (I actually reverted back to the original method of using the -v flag, and discovered that the mounted folder was a step up the file system, outside of the APP folder. D'uh!) Swiftly on the next problem though, ha!